# Full bridge inverter using IR2110 giving output in patches

Tags: inverter, high-frequency, gate-driving, full-bridge

I have made a full-bridge inverter using [IR211](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/323402/IRF/IR2110.html)0 IC. The MOSFETs used are [IRF540n](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/68172/IRF/IRF540N.html). The bootstrap capacitor is 4.7uf. The diodes used are [1N5819](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/94864/VISHAY/1N5819.html) high-frequency Schottky diodes. The operating frequency is 50KHz. The input signal is given using an Arduino Uno. 1.5kohm gate to source resistor is also connected. The pictures of the inverter are shown below.

[image]

The power to both ICs is given using a single isolated 12V power supply. The 5V signal is also given using the same supply with the help of the LM7805 regulator. The picture is shown below.

[image]

The input DC signal is given from the DC supply of 31V. The output is taken across a 5Kohm 10W resistor.
The issue is that the output signal is not consistent. The signal comes for some periods of time. The output signal picture is shown below.

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

[image]

The areas in which the output is coming is absolutely correct. But overall it is not coming. The ICs are tested they are working fine.

[image]

Can anybody tell what can be the issue. Is the 5v and 12v signal must be given from separate isolated supplies or that is not the problem.
This is the schematic diagram.

[image]

Regards

Comment: Where's your schematic diagram? Prototype board is fairly useless for these sort of circuits unless you are exceptionally careful and knowledgeable but, if you were careful and knowledgeable you'd have laid it out on a PCB!

Comment: @Andyaka I am attaching the schematic.

Comment: Note to other members here: The same question from the OP is active at the [All About Circuits forum](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/full-bridge-inverter-using-ir2110-giving-output-in-patches.177397/) where new information and replies have already been added. So for anyone interested in the topic, to avoid duplication of effort, it's probably worth checking for any updates *there* which have not been added *here*.